# C++ Win32 : Attach a child window to main window

Tags: c++, window, mdi

I am working on a program base on C++ and also using SiliconSoftware interface. 
as you see from the attached pisture I am running the main window with the c++ win32 code, but the display window is created with frame grabber inteface with following code :

```
int Bits=8; int nId =::CreateDisplay(Bits,GrabberOptions::getWidth(),GrabberOptions::getHeight());SetBufferWidth(nId,GrabberOptions::getWidth(),GrabberOptions::getHeight());::DrawBuffer(nId,Fg_getImagePtrEx(fg,lastPicNr,0,_memoryAllc),lastPicNr,"");
```

but I want this Diplay window, open with within the Main Window. 
How can I do it ? any idea? 
[image]

Comment: This is not native Win32. You're actually using some C++ wrapper you've to better specify

Comment: I created my project with Visual Stadio, but I didnt used the "Empty Project" Option, so the main window has been created by the Visual Studio I assume this is the code for the window : BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;
   
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

Comment: There's no way to "attach" a window after it's been created. If the frame grabber API doesn't give you the option then you're out of luck.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You can call SetWindowLong to reset the WS_POPUP and set the WS_CHILD style bits (and also to remove the WS_CAPTION ...) and call SetParent to make a window to become effectively child of another, and then cal SetWindowPos to properly place it.

The point, here, is understanding if he can access the native handles or not...

Comment: Dear Emilio thank you for putting your time on this, I think I have access to native handles. what do you suggesst. I am working on your solution, trying to run a simple code.

Comment: @Emilio Do I need to create a new window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
HWND a = ...
HWND b = ...
```

assumig they are the native handles of sibling window obtained no matter how.
To make b a child of a, you have to do

```
Setparent(b,a); //a will be the new parent b
DWORD style = GetWindowLong(b,GWL_STYLE); //get the b style
style &= ~(WS_POPUP|WS_CAPTION); //reset the "caption" and "popup" bits
style |= WS_CHILD; //set the "child" bit
SetWindowLong(b,GWL_STYLE,style); //set the new style of b
RECT rc; //temporary rectangle
GetClientRect(a,&rc); //the "inside border" rectangle for a
MoveWindow(b,rc.left,rc.top,rc.right-rc.left,rc.bottom-rc.top); //place b at (x,y,w,h) in a
UpdateWindow(a);
```

Nowm you have to handle WM_SIZE from a and move b accordingly, so that it resize together with its (new) parent.